# mysql issue, failing to add the foreign key constraint with missing index

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql so apologies if this is a silly question. I am trying to create a new table and it is giving me the following error "Error Code: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'results_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'predictors'" Apologies if the format isn't good, I am unaware on how mysql should be displayed on Stack. I have inputted data into the "predictors" table, however don't know how to add it into a Stack table. Also when I write Primary Key in brackets in the tables, that is just to signify that it is the primary key, it is not actually written in the table.

Thanks for your time,

Code

```
CREATE TABLE results (
                   Predictor_Result_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                   Predictor_ID INT,
                   Predictor_Name VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_ID INT,
                   Match_Name VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Result VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Specific_Result VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Specific_Result_Plus VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Prediction VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Specific_Prediction VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Specific_Prediction_Plus VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Prediction_SuccessOrFail VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Specific_Prediction_SuccessOrFail VARCHAR(50),
                   Match_Specific_Prediction_Plus_SuccessOrFail VARCHAR(50),
                   PRIMARY KEY (Predictor_Result_ID),
                   FOREIGN KEY (Predictor_ID) REFERENCES predictors(Predictor_ID),
                   FOREIGN KEY (Predictor_Name) REFERENCES predictors(Predictor_Name),
                   FOREIGN KEY (Match_ID) REFERENCES matches(Match_ID),
                   FOREIGN KEY (Match_Name) REFERENCES matches(Match_Name),
                   FOREIGN KEY (Match_Result) REFERENCES matches(Match_Result),
                   FOREIGN KEY (Match_Specific_Result) REFERENCES 
                                matches(Match_Specific_Result),
                   FOREIGN KEY (Match_Specific_Result_Plus) REFERENCES 
                                matches(Match_Specific_Result_Plus)
                  )
```

Tables

Table Title: matches

| Match_ID (Primary Key) | Match_Name | Match_Result | Match_Specific_Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Match_Specific_Result_Plus | Match_Name |  |  |
| ---------------------------- | ------------ |  |  |

Table Title: predictors

| Predictor_ID (Primary Key) | Predictor_Name |
| --- | --- |

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate columns between the two tables. Just use a foreign key to link to the related row, and get the other columns by joining.

Comment: The error is because the `predictors` table doesn't have an index on `Predictor_Name`. You need to add that index.

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that the FOREIGN KEY constraint on `results` is referring to a column on the other table that is not indexed. Specifically you would need to create an index on `predictors.Predictor_Name`. This will probably also apply to `matches.Match_Name` and the other constraints you have defined.

However, it seems unlikely that you'd need constraints on ID as well as the other columns. Consider just using constraints on the IDs